# Replace a bathroom drop in sink with cut out of 15" x 24"

Tags: bathroom

Need to replace a bathroom drop in sink with cutout of 15" x 24". Have not found a sink that will fit those dimensions.  Any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: While I can guess what you are looking for, I am not willing to offer any suggestion to a vague question. Please provide more detail and take a photo on the drop in sink.

Answer (score 1):

Three options, if you can't find an off-the-shelf solution:

- Different size sink

Depending on (a) the type of countertop and (b) location of cabinets and other constraints, you may be able to use a slightly larger sink and cut a bigger hole. I am less optimistic (unless you are ready/willing/able to replace the countertop) about using a smaller sink.

- Custom sink

This is not necessarily as expensive as you might think. There are national companies (e.g., available directly or by special order in any Big Orange or Blue store) and also local suppliers. I have a countertop with integral sink from one of these companies (a local one, but via a Big Orange store for ordering/delivery). Look for "cultured marble" or "engineered stone" - euphemisms for "crushed stone mixed with resin", which can be formed into almost any shape/size and with a wide range of colors available. Ideal, in my opinion, for a bathroom, and much more easily (and inexpensively) customizable than natural stone. These companies will typically have standard sizes but since each order is custom (exact length on countertops, color selection, etc.) a custom sink is not out of the ordinary.

- New Countertop with Integral Sink

Depending on dimensions, this may not be so expensive. Of course, if you already have a nice countertop in good condition then this may seem like a waste of money & material. But I think it is worth considering, especially in the same "cultured marble" as you might order for a sink by itself.